# How to test logistic regression code written from scratch?

Tags: python, testing, logistic-regression

I have written a logistic regression program scratch using numpy. Can you guys give me some pointer to how to test the code? I tried using a spam email database, but it is huge. I can't debug. Is there any smaller dataset / any other way to test my code? Thanks

Comment: how do you apply that to email database ? To test just generate some simple numerical function

Comment: Thanks. I understand how to generate data for linear regression. But how do i do it for logistic regression? Did you mean if the output of sigmoid is less than 0.5,it belongs to 0 and if greater then belongs to 1?

Comment: not realy, you would like clear output, means 0.01 or less i 0, 0.99 or greater is 1 and everythin else is unknown and must not come out. Ok if you know linear regression, the only difference is you apply sigmoid for forward pass and apply delta * sig_layer(1-sig_layer) on backward